# How jolly identified you are sharing fake details in RRPG game?

Tags: story

You recently registered in RRPG game example YOWORLD to make random friends,  you have changed the gender of your avatar to female but in actual you are male. It is not possible to identify your gender until and unless you tell them by yourself in-game chat. you also gave you avatar a girl name "Angelina". the game also cannot identify your gender. you are not a citizen of the US. you met a boy name jolly who is a citizen of the US and he asked you several questions. where you live? you told him new-york. your age? you told him 16. hobbies? you told him video games. school? you searched the new york schools on google and told him Regis high school. the next day when you log in into the game you got the inbox form jolly saying you are a fake, you liar.

you asked him to prove that you are fake...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is that you said:

> You attended Regis High School

This is a problem because:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regis_High_School_(New_York_City)
>  It is a school for "young men".  Since you said you are a female, this is contradictory.

Comment: Ah beaten out by a few seconds. Nicely done!

Answer (score 1):

> Regis high school is a private boys-only school in New York. So from jolly's point of view either you are lying about being a girl, lying about where you went to school, or both.

Comment: Who is Holly? "So from Holly's point of view"

Comment: An unnoticed typo. Meant to be jolly. Fixed it.

Comment: Oh... Thought Holly was someone's name :)